# How to modify an XP driver to work with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I have a simple controller adapter that allows me to use my PS2 controller in Windows XP.  I upgraded to Windows 7 and it doesn't detect the adapter, even though Windows XP did.  Is there a way to get Windows 7 to work with this  adapter, since it worked in XP?  Can I modify the driver that XP used so that it can work in Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've already resolved this issue, but I want to point out something for the future: Very nearly all XP installs were 32-bit only. Therefore, most manufacturers and driver-writers only provided 32-bit drivers for XP. While you can still get 32-bit Windows versions, starting with Vista more and more people began installing 64-bit versions of Windows. While 64-bit Windows can run 32-bit user-mode programs, it can *not* load 32-bit kernel-mode programs. This means that a driver for XP will almost never work on a 64-bit Windows version, and 32-bit Windows installs are becoming rarer and rarer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try installing the driver while in [Compatiblity Mode](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/316-compatibility-mode.html). If you happen to have a newer machine that Windows 7 is installed on you can so try out [Windows XP Mode for Windows 7](http://community.winsupersite.com/blogs/paul/archive/2009/04/24/secret-no-more-revealing-virtual-windows-xp-for-windows-7.aspx) . Third, Windows Update has alot of drivers that don't install the first time around. Run Windows update and see if your hardware has an optional driver installation that you can download. Last, you might try your manufactuer's website and see if they have any new drivers for you to dowload for your hardware.

If all of this fails, you might have to fallback and purchase some new hardware.

Good luck, and hope this helps some.

Answer (score -1):

If this is really the problem, I think that modifying the driver is probably not the way to go.  If a program crashes, you just lose what you were doing with that program, if a driver screws up, you BSOD the box.

Have you checked the manufacturer's site for a new driver?

Comment: I tried plugging it in again and this time Windows 7 recognized it and installed the right driver.

Comment: @Phenom nice! I'm glad it works :)